# Ionic project types: --type=angular vs --type=ionic-angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am confused on what project type should I use. In official Ionic docs they suggest to create a new project by running - `ionic start MyApp tutorial --type=ionic-angular`. But from other source I found that I could `ionic start MyApp tutorial --type=angular`, which makes my life easier because I could use for ex. `ng add` to add dependencies and the project structure is like Angular. However, `--type=angular` doesnt have `super` project type, so I can't generate new app with `ionic start MyApp super --type=angular`, I can live with that, but need some advices on which project type is preferred - what criteria for choosing one over another (`--type=angular` vs `--type=ionic-angular`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Ionic 4 you should use the cmmmand,

```
ionic start MyApp tutorial --type=angular
```

whereas in Ionic3 you would have used

```
ionic start MyApp tutorial --type=ionic-angular
```

basically going forward you should use the first way. However i would recommend to build apps using **[capcitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/)** which makes life easier

Comment: Do you know how to see what official templates provides Ionic4? For ex. Ionic3 gives - tabs, sidemenu, blank, super, tutorial

Comment: use my slides if you are starting with ionic 4 https://slides.com/sajeetharansinnathurai/ionicnsbm#/8

Comment: This is the official documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/starting